# how can i html popup tooltip scraping

Tags: javascript, html, beautifulsoup

While I was doing web scraping,
Popup tooltip has data, so I tried to get the data
I couldn't get the page source because I had to get the mouse
How do I solve this problem?

popup tooltip page source:

```
<div id="popup-table-given-rdps-ability-17-0_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper dt-jqueryui no-footer"><div class="fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr"></div><table width="100%" id="popup-table-given-rdps-ability-17-0" cellspacing="0" class="summary-table dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid">
<thead>
    <tr role="row"><th nowrap="" class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="popup-table-given-rdps-ability-17-0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Given By Ability: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Given By Ability<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div></th><th class="sorting ui-state-default sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="popup-table-given-rdps-ability-17-0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" aria-label="Amount: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Amount<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></div></th><th class="sorting ui-state-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="popup-table-given-rdps-ability-17-0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="DPS: activate to sort column ascending"><div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">DPS<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></span></div></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr style="vertical-align:middle" role="row" class="odd">
<td style="min-width:120px" tabindex="0">
<img data-src="https://assets.rpglogs.com/img/ff/abilities/012000-012532.png" class="tiny-icon lazyload" "="" src="https://assets.rpglogs.com/img/ff/abilities/012000-012532.png">

<span class="Monk">Brotherhood</span>
```

199275.89001155$4.46%199.3k
    451.6

If I don't put the mouse, I can't see the source of the page

Comment: Please include your current code, the url and the desired output value.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the inspector and select :hov on the element you want to inspect to simulate the mouse over without keeping the mouse on the element.
[image]